# How to dispalay icons of django site after deploying

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, icons, font-awesome

Hello I recently deployed a django website on heroku and used aws to store my media and static files, the site was deployed successfully except i cant find the icons used by the template on production but those icons work locally what can i do to solve this. Thank you in anticipation of your favourable response

Comment: What is the error ? Can you provide some code or examples ? It is hard to help with so few information

Comment: Post your `settings.py` so we can see what you have set for your `STATICFILES` attribute.